# Espresso parent view click

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-espresso

```
 <LinearLayout [...]
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
        tools:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I click on the child itens on ExpandableListView using espresso, where "blahblahblah" is my item view id as following sample.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:id="@+id/blahblahblah"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: You want to click on the root `View` of an item from your `ListView`?

Comment: click on item view, I misstyped.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Espresso.onData` method. The exact way depends on how you wanna specify which item of the `ExpandableListView` you want to choose.

Usually you would use one of those two approaches:

### 1. Match `data` in your `Adapter`:

Assuming your `ExpandableListAdapter` data is based on `MyData` objects:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    List<MyData> data = new ArrayList();

    //... all the other stuff you need for it to work

}
```

You would use `Espresso.onData` to match the desired record (for example by matching its `toString()` method):

```
onData(hasToString(containsString("example"))
        .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.options))
        .onChildView(withId(R.id.blablabla))
        .perform(click());
```

(the `toString()` of the particular `MyData` object must contain `String` `"example"`)

### 2. Match `position` in your `Adapter`:

Regardless of the data your child object is associated with, match `position` in your `ListView` (in the example `position == 0`):

```
onData(anything())
        .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.options))
        .atPosition(0)
        .onChildView(withId(R.id.blablabla))
        .perform(click());
```